# How to avoid circular dependency in components?

Tags: angular

I have a root component `app-document-form` that iterates the children elements of object `documentBlock`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let element of documentBlock?.children"> <!-- This is important part -->
     <app-adresat-list *ngIf="element.tag === 'ADRESAT'" [parentBlock]="documentBlock"></app-adresat-list>
</ng-container>
```

If current `element` is `element.tag === 'ADRESAT'` I show a component `app-adresat-list`.

Component template `app-adresat-list` is:

```
<app-adresat [parentBlock]="parentBlock" [element]="element" *ngFor="let element of adresatList"></app-adresat>
```

The `app-adresat` is:

```
{{element.title}
<div class="document-block__body">
   <app-document-form [documentBlock]="element"></app-document-form>
</div>
```

The `app-adresat` uses again `app-document-form` component to continues go deeper in structure.

So that is why I get circular dependency: `app-document-form` -> `app-adresat-list` -> `app-adresat` -> `app-document-form` -> `app-adresat-list`.

So, it is easy to solve removing `<app-document-form [documentBlock]="element"></app-document-form>` from `app-adresat`. But I need call it because `app-adresat` can have children elements that should be displayed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. You can use the `<ng-content></ng-content>` tag as a placeholder for that dynamic content, then when the template is parsed Angular will replace that placeholder tag with your content.

add `<ng-content></ng-content>` to your component and pass the component yo want to the component.

> ```
> <app-document>
>   <app-addressat ad="address 1">
>     <app-addressat ad="address 2">
>       <app-document title="document 1">
>         <app-addressat ad="address 3"></app-addressat>
>       </app-document>
>     </app-addressat>
>   </app-addressat>
> </app-document>
> ```

[stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/nestedcomponenthansand?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Comment: Thank you a lot, I will try, so dont call initial component  `app-document-form`? Right?

Comment: Could you help me to do this dynamically with initial object `documentBlock?.children`? How to build this structure of components based on json object from root node `documentBlock?.children`?

Comment: My initial object is: `let obj = {id: 1, children: [{id: 4,  children: [{id: 5}]}]}`